# XAML preview not working on Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin.Forms app with mvvmcross

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app with Visual Studio 2017 using MVVMCross.
The XAML preview doesn't work with the default App.xaml

[image: App.xaml issue]

And if I open some MvvmCross view I don't have the option at all

[image: No XAML preview option]

Should it work? Any pointers?

Comment: the previewer in 2017 is bad. Microsoft claims improvements in 2019, so install VS2019 and look if it works there.

Comment: have you tried VS2019 community edition?

Answer (score 0):

What to do is checking up Resharper Options > Enviroment > Performance Guide > Disable XAML Designer.

It must be "Ignore" or "Show in Status Bar". Otherwise, it's always disabling XAML Designer.

Comment: It was in Show in Status Bar, anyway I changed to ignore, and still not working